# How to Mock MongoDB's GetCollection method

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, filter, moq

I am using Moq for mocking purpose.

I am looking for mocking MongoDB's `GetCollection` method in C#. MongoDB's 2.7.0 driver is being used in the code.

```
var filter = ....; //my business logic

var filteredData = await _mongoDb.GetCollection<MongoResult>("someKey").FindAsync(filter);
```

The idea is to test the filter condition as part of the test case.

Thus, I am looking for mocking `_mongoDb.GetCollection<MongoResult>` so that I can pass in my custom collection and then filter can be tested.

I have tried approaches mentioned in different posts in Stack Overflow. However, none of them seem to work (so far).